spring-batch-extension for bigquery. Any samples available?
I am trying to read a big dataset from GCP bigquery via spring batch and then call an API with each record. With Spring batch i am hoping to use chunk based step.
I came across the spring-batch-bigquery Github package. Which seems to be doing what I want. I also went over the other question related it BigQuery for Spring batch Reader instead of RDMS.
Looking at the above question i have a few queries and i am unable to post comments on this question.

The BigQueryReader is still not released in maven. Any plans to release it? Is the recommendation that i copy the entire bigquery extension and then use it?
I could not find a sample usage of the package. Please help point me to the right example if there is one on how to use it.
It seems the data is loaded as an iterator, so it should be read one line at a time but in this question the reporter mentioned all data is loaded all at the same time. Could you please help clarify. My requirement is also to not load all data at once.

I want to use something out of the box if possible. If that is not feasible, i would want to use something which is a recommended solution. In this case would it be?

JdbcCursorItemReader (already restartable)
JdbcPagingItemReader (already restartable)
customReader (using GCP BigQuery starter) + Making it restartable

I am new to SpringBoot+Batch and not well versed on the flexibility of it, so i might be missing a few key points, please bear with me on that.
Thanks!
Went over BigQuery for Spring batch Reader instead of RDMS.
and How to fetch BigQuery data into a springboot application?
Could not find any other examples of how to using bigquery with spring batch.
